# Integration of the product of sin and exponential with power

Tags: integration

$$\ \int_0^{\pi} \bigl(\sin(x)\bigr)^{2n-2k+1} e^{a\cos(x)} dx , \qquad a,n,k\in\mathbb Z.$$
I tried to solve this integral by parts, but I didn't get any result. I look forward to your experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_0^{\pi} (\sin x)^{2n-2k+1} e^{a\cos x} dx =\int_{-1}^1 (1-\xi^2)^{n-k}e^{a\xi}\,d\xi$$
$$\qquad\qquad=\sqrt{\pi }\, 2^{-k+n+\frac{1}{2}} a^{\frac{1}{2} (2 k-2 n-1)} \Gamma (-k+n+1) I_{\frac{1}{2} (-2 k+2 n+1)}(a),\;\;n-k+1>0,$$
with $I_\alpha(x)$ the modified Bessel function of the first kind.

Comment: Can you provide more details?

Comment: for the integral over $\xi$ see the formula 3.387.1 in Gradshteyn & Ryzhik.

Comment: What is $I_\lambda(a)$ ?

Comment: @PietroMajer -- $I_\lambda(a)$ is the Bessel function of the first kind; for $\lambda$ half integer it reduces to $\sinh$ and $\cosh$ terms.

Comment: Will there be an effect if a belongs to the real numbers?

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{0}^{\pi}(\sin x)^{2n-2k+1}e^{a\cos x}dx$$
To avoid writing $n-k$ all the times let $v=n-k$.
$$u=\cos x \implies du=-\sin x\,dx$$
$$\int_{-1}^{+1}(1-u^2)^{v} e^{au}du$$
Split the integral at 0 and we have,
$$2\int_{0}^{1}(1-u^2)^{v}\cosh(au)du$$
(Because $\cosh x=\frac{e^a+e^{-a}}{2}$)
$t=u^{2}\implies dt=2u\,du$
$$\int_{0}^{1}(1-t)^{v}\cosh(a\sqrt[2]{t})t^{\frac{-1}{2}}dt$$
Taylor series expansion of hyperbolic cosine gives us,
$$\cosh(x)=\sum_{z\ge 0}\frac{x^{2z}}{(2z)!}$$
Placing this in the integrand and bringing the summation outside the integrand,
$$\sum_{z\ge 0}\left(\frac{a^{2z}}{(2z)!}\int_{0}^{1}(1-t)^{(v+1)-1}t^{(z+1)-1}dt\right)$$
$$\sum_{z\ge 0}\frac{a^{2z}(B(z+1,v+1))}{(2z)!}$$
Taking certain values of $v$, $a$ we can calculate the value of integrand by using properties of beta function.
$$B(x,y)=\frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$$
Having the values of $v,a\in\mathbb{Z}$ we can use the above the relation and simplify the summation.